# How to listen to future path in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can we listen in advanced to a non existed path on firebase which going to be created in the future outside the app(via the server side) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to listen to a location in the database that doesn't exist yet.  It works just like any other listener, and your code will get invoked as soon as data is written to that location.

Comment: are you sure?  because if we set roles for a path and the path not exists (yet) we get access denied. for example:

"rules": {
    ".write": false
"players": {
              "$playerId": {
                ".read": "some-read-role"
              }
...
if i try to listen on players/$player-id-that-not-exist-yet iam getting access denied

Comment: Of course, the query has to satisfy any rules you set up.  You can't make a query until the rules allow it.  Ignoring rules (which you didn't specify in your question), what I said in my answer is definitely true.

Comment: so if we have rules how would you solve my initial question?

Comment: Change the rules to allow the query, or accept that your rules don't allow reading an empty location. This sounds like a whole new question to me.

Comment: you right. i forgot to mention the roles. any chance for a hint?:)

Comment: I think you should ask a whole new question stating the new problem you're running into with your rules and the query you're trying to make.